# Going to sell soon but HVAC died. Affect on sticker price depending on manufacturer, and additional duct work?

Tags: hvac

My 30+ year old 2T builder's grade Comfortmaker 8 SEER recently blew its last, and I need to figure out a good replacement. I leaned toward Carrier because it has a good reputation and that's what the builders put in the new homes around here in the southeast United States. The house is a 3300 square foot three story Williamsburg style. About 1100 sf are on first floor, 1100 sf on 2nd floor, and the rest in the currently unfinished basement (I'd like to finish the 500 sf side opposite the cars and thought that might affect the size put in for the first floor).

My children are not interested in inheriting and maintaining this house, so I plan to sell it within next couple of years or earlier. My initial thought is that a 2T 14 SEER Carrier upstairs would be sufficient. The old system always cooled unevenly with some cold rooms and some barely tolerable. I'm not sure even a 14 SEER would fix that but it would be an improvement on what I had.

Also planned to put up new vent fans in the attic. One guy wouldn't even go up to look and measure furnace. I surmised the downstairs unit could be replaced with a 2.5 ton possibly 16 SEER single (currently 2.5 T 10 SEER) or even a 14 SEER. I wasn't getting a whole lot of help from the three companies that came to give estimates. One pushed a 3 ton upstairs and downstairs. I'd always heard that too much could lead to mold and mildew problems.

Also there seemed to be a difference of opinion between companies as to whether the current R22 lines would have to be replaced with R1410A lines and whether a new vent hole would have to be cut in the ceiling upstairs. I'm surprised all of these NATE guys with the same training say such different things and am looking for some clarification. Can you please help? Thanks

Comment: Does the existing system have two air conditioners in it?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I thought 1 originally. But on further reading, sounds like 2 units, which makes sense as I can't see a single 2T handling that big a house. My answer isn't affected, but others might be, as this would presumably mean the duct work is already split up into two zones, etc.

Comment: *"difference of opinion between companies"* is because they make money selling equipment, not putting it in, and an r22 is say, $1k and no line set. 410-a is more like $2k and a $500 lineset.

Comment: Talk with several local realtors (or zillow or other house pricing web sites) if you want to find out the effect of a particular upgrade on sales price in your area.

Answer (score 4):

Shopping questions are officially off-topic. So "which model is best" isn't a question that you'll get an answer to here. But some key things to keep in mind:

- Size of the unit is measured in tons of cooling. There are other ways to measure (e.g., BTU) but they all mean the same thing. So if a 2 Ton unit was enough for your house, then a new 2 Ton unit should be fine. Perhaps a little larger might be better, but as you already know, putting in a *much* larger unit is not a good idea.
- SEER is a measure of *efficiency*. Which translates into how much you need to spend on electricity to run the unit, and indirectly on how good/bad for the environment. The higher the SEER number, the less it will cost you to run. But a high SEER number doesn't make a 2 Ton unit produce 3 Tons of cooling or cool your house any faster or better on a hot day.

In a perfect world (or my definition of a perfect world), everyone would look at the *total cost of ownership*. How much does the unit cost to buy and install + how much will the energy costs be over the expected lifetime of the unit. Add it up and buy whatever is least expensive *total cost*. Which would likely mean that most people would buy a fairly efficient unit because it would pay in the long run. But most people, in my experience, look only at the up-front cost. As a result, government often steps in (to varying degrees) to force the issue by some combination of:

- Rebates to lower the price of high efficiency units
- Requiring a minimum efficiency, sometimes varying by location (e.g., force higher efficiency units in areas where air conditioning is used the most and therefore provides the most benefit by lowering energy usage)
- Rebates to encourage replacement of old units, regardless of specific efficiency (since most older units are lower efficiency than most newer units, plus older units are likely to be running even lower than the original design efficiency due to other factors)

and many of these things, especially rebates on new units, affect total cost of ownership. (Same idea as "free" CFL (years ago) and LED bulbs, subsidies on electric vehicles, etc.)

As to your specific situation:

- If you are *really* planning to move in a few years, obviously long-term energy costs may not be at the top of your list. But sometimes people stay put many years longer than they originally planned. And efficient systems can be a good selling point too, particularly if energy prices keep going up.
- Hot and cold spots *might* be affected by the size of the unit, though likely as much the air handler as the compressor. But more likely are issues with poorly designed (or broken) duct work. Increasing or decreasing duct size in various parts of the house can make a big difference in balancing the system.
- You should be able to put in a full heat pump that provides both heating and air conditioning for little more than the cost of new air conditioning systems. The equipment is almost identical. The biggest problem with heat pumps is in areas with very cold winters, but done properly you can keep an existing heating system (e.g., forced air natural gas) as backup for the really cold days and save on your heating bill as well as your cooling bill.

Comment: Can the DVer please explain their rationale?

Comment: That's a bit too simplistic. I would not necessarily trust manufacturer specified performance figures, but SEER itself is a very simple calculation that offsets cooling output to electricity consumption.

Comment: Not my DV, but I'd guess that it's for answering a question that you acknowledge is OT.

Comment: Do not answer such blatantly off-topic questions. Answers interfere with the removal of closed off-topic questions.

Comment: @nobody I (obviously) disagree. In this case, OP was throwing around all sorts of information and IMHO needed some general information about SEER and other topics in order to be an educated shopper. That's not exactly what OP asked, but I think it was OP really needs. The last step (selection of specific products and/or vendors) is off-topic.